# How do I make my server do all the loading and javascript and then server the page all ready

Tags: javascript, html, oracle

I got a webpage that calls oracle and then does some processing and then a lot of javascript.

The problem is that all of this make it slow for the user. I have to use internet explorer 6 so the javascript takes very long to load, around 15 seconds.

How can i make my server do all of this every minute for example and save the page so if a user requests it it would server them that page that is all ready calculated etc

im using tomcat server my webpage is mainly javascript and html

**edit:**
By the way I can not rewrite my webpage, it would have to remain as it is

I'm looking for something that would give the user a snapshot of the webpage that the server loaded

Comment: If you can't change the page, your question makes no sense.  What are you asking for?

Comment: @SLaks I'm looking for a script or a tecnology that would almost save the webpage on the server as you would with File>>Save as... and then serve that

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you'd need to have your server build up the DOM, run the JavaScript in an environment that looks (enough) like web browser, and then serialize the result as HTML.

There have been various attempts to do that, [Jaxer](http://jaxer.org/) is one of them (it was originally a product from Aptana, now an Apache project). Another related answer here on SO pointed to the [jsdom project](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom), which is a DOM implementation in JavaScript ([video here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/theater/video.php?v=insua-dom)).

Re

> By the way I can not rewrite my webpage, it would have to remain as it is

That's very unlikely to be successful. There is bound to be *some* modification involved. At the very least, you're going to have to tell your server-side framework what parts it should process and what parts should be left to the client (e.g., user-interaction code).

**Edit**:

You might also look for "website thumbnail" services like [shrinktheweb.com](http://www.shrinktheweb.com/) and similar. Their "pro" account allows full-size thumbnails (what I don't know is whether it's an image or HTML). But I'm not specifically suggesting them, just a line you might pursue. If you can find a project that does thumbnails, you may be able to adapt it to do what you want.

But again, take a look at Jaxer, you may find that it does what you need or very similar (and it's open-source, so you can modify it or extract the bits you want).

Comment: You know how you have remote desktop, Isn't there some technology that does something like but instead of showing your the desktop... it would show you the webpage that the server updates. sorry i know sounds rediculous but worth asking

Comment: @user: It's not ridiculous, and there are lots of applications for it (thumbnails of websites, for instance). That might be a line of discovery for you, actually, look for projects that do "thumbnails" as they would have to do basically what you're looking at doing.

Answer (score 0):

YSlow recommendations would tell you that you should put all your CSS in the head of your page and all JavaScript at the bottom, just before the closing body tag.  This will allow the page to fully load the DOM and render it.

You should also minify and compress your JavaScript to reduce download size.

Answer (score 0):

"How can i make my server do all of this every minute for example"

If you are asking how you can make your database server 'pre-run' a query, then look into materialized views.

If the Oracle query is responsible for (for example) 10 seconds of the delay there may be other things you can do to speed it up, but we'd need a lot more information on what the query does